# jQuery appended() positioning

Tags: jquery, css, position, append

I have to remove() a few iems from my website and then append() them back, but when I do append them they appear in different places while I want them to be displayed exactly at he same place where they used to be.

Is there any fix to that?

Here's a sandbox, feel free to update (notice how image changes postion after the first appending):

http://jsfiddle.net/Zt9tZ/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there's some additional information I'm missing here, but why remove it entirely?  Is there any reason you can't just use `hide` and `show`?

http://jsfiddle.net/Zt9tZ/10/

The problem with appending is that you add the element as the last one to the parent.  If you really have to remove the element entirely for some reason, you could put some sort of placeholder in its place.  Perhaps with `replaceWith` and some invisible element that will later be replaced again with the original element.

---

Alternatively, you could keep track of the nearest sibling and use `insertBefore` or `insertAfter`.

EDIT: An example of `insertAfter`:

```
var image = jQuery(".image"); 
var prev;

jQuery("#remove").click(function(){
    prev = image.prev();
    image.remove();
});

jQuery("#append").click(function(){
    if(prev.length === 0){
        // element was first
        jQuery("#container").prepend(image);
    }else{
        image.insertAfter(prev);   
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zt9tZ/12/

---

EDIT2:  Example of `replaceWith`:

```
var image = jQuery(".image"); 
var replacement = $("<div></div>");

jQuery("#remove").click(function(){
    image.replaceWith(replacement);
});

jQuery("#append").click(function(){
    replacement.replaceWith(image);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zt9tZ/13/

Comment: yeah, as I said before I can't hide() these elements - they are embedded videos and still playing after hiding (you can actually hear them). I'm going to play with your methods as they are probably something I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In that particular case, you should use `.prepend()` instead, to put it back at the beginning of the selected element, rather than at the end.

Comment: @Natie B thank you, but how about differently positioned elements?

Answer (score 1):

I would do a absolute position CSS for the image.

**CSS**

```
.imageStatic
{
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:45px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var image = jQuery(".imageStatic"); 

jQuery("#remove").click(function(){
    var image = jQuery(".imageStatic").remove();
});

jQuery("#append").click(function(){
    jQuery("#container").append(image);
    $("#container img").addClass("imageStatic");
})
```

working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/Zt9tZ/9/

Comment: upvoted, clever idea, but this is not what I really need, I'm not able to set absolute positions to every removed() item especially when they are being positioned using div grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hide() and show() to achieve the same effect, but the elements will stay in position.

Basically, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4JQ9m/

Comment: I can't use hide, opacity or visibility, I have to entirely remove an element as it is playing flash content :)